# Meaning of the phrasal verb "back up on" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

I've come across it in the 8th episode of the 3rd season of *Rick and Morty*. Here is the context:

> Rick: Oh, [BLEEP]! Oh, [BLEEP]! [Bleep] me! [Bleep] me! Rick! Ah, [BLEEP], Morty, what did you do? All right, Morty, pack your shit! That’s only gonna keep ‘em down for a little bit, Morty! You [BLEEP] with squirrels, Morty! We got a good five minutes before they’re **backing up on** our ass, Morty! We have to pack up and move to a new reality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a road is blocked, or partly blocked by slow moving traffic, the cars behind will form a queue behind the blockage.  We would say that the traffic is "backing up"

> There has been an accident in Beckton on the A406, and traffic is backed up as far as Barking.  Avoid the area if possible.

Here (for humorous effect) Rick seems to be worried about a long queue of angry squirrels forming, behind his "ass".